# Como puedo mostrar los resultados de un JSON en un AlertDialog?

Tags: android

estoy tratando de mostrar los resultados de mi Json en un AlertDialog, usando la clase AsyncTask, logre a procesar la url , pero no tengo idea como mostrar los resultados final dentro de un listView, en mi onPostExecute...  Algún ayuda por favor
ahi esta mi codigo...

```
new AsyncTask<String, String, String>() {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertdialogbuilder ;
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            alertdialogbuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            alertdialogbuilder.setTitle("Que Lineas Desees?");

        }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
           // alertdialogbuilder.setTitle("De Que Lineas ?");
            final String url = "http://mirUrl.com";
            prod = new ArrayList<>();
            HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();
            JSONObject jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);
            JSONObject jsonObj = null;
            try {
                jsonObj = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(jsonStr));
                JSONArray contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("CATEGORIAS");
                for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);
                    String descripcion = c.getString("nombre");

                    HashMap<String, String> contacto = new HashMap<>();

                    contacto.put("nombre", descripcion);

                    prod.add(contacto);
                    Log.d("REGLON", String.valueOf(prod));
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
     return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);

            // aca deberia mostrar el resultado final  supongo...

            AlertDialog dialog = alertdialogbuilder.create();
            dialog.show();
        }

    }.execute();
```

Comment: Gracias @Jorgesys por su ayuda... Hice un Log para ver si procesa la url , si lo procesa obtengo el resultado que queria , que seria el NOMBRE DE CADA CATEORIA... mi problema es como cargarlo en una lista ..dentro de un alertdialog....

Comment: Gracias bro con tu codigo agregue algo y funciona... Saludo @Jorgesys

Answer (score 1):

Logre a mostrar los resultados en de mi JSON en el AlertDialog asunando AsyncTask...
ahi deje la repuesta de mi onPostExecute ...

```
   @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), prod,
                    R.layout.item_fabricante,
                    new String[]{"nombre"},
                    new int[]{R.id.txtSeccion});
            alertdialogbuilder.setAdapter(simpleAdapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int itemIndex) {
                //    Hace lo que tu quieras..
                }
            });
            alertdialogbuilder.setCancelable(false);
            alertdialogbuilder.create();
            alertdialogbuilder.show();
        }


    }.execute();
```

Answer (score -1):

Revisando tu código dentro `doInBackground()` agregas valores a un `ArrayList` llamado `prod` por lo tanto en tu `AlertDialog` puedes mostrar los valores de esta forma:

```
 AlertDialog dialog = alertdialogbuilder.create();
 dialog.setMessage(prod.toString());
 dialog.show();
```

Comment: **Cuando se califique con -1, es bueno para el sitio se indique la razón**, esto para mejorar la pregunta, eliminarla o si existen argumentos platicar sobre el tema.